# KVM guests not able to ping each other

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, bridge

Ahoy friends.
Currently i am running my Fedora 30 host, using Cockpit and cockpit-virtual-machines in order to manage my machines.
I got my network interface enp35s0, and a vlan subinterface enp35s0.220, and the bridge created on enp35s0, bridge200.
All my guests are connected to bridge200 as "directly attached", and internet access works quite fine.
Unfortunately all these guests are not able to ping, or access each other. They only retrieve their ip's through DNS but can't ping each other at all.
What's the best approach to go for in this case?
All guests are in the 192.168.200.0/24 subnet.
What might be the issue here?
Thanks in advance!

```
PING freenas.lan (192.168.200.79) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.200.60 (192.168.200.60) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.200.60 (192.168.200.60) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.200.60 (192.168.200.60) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Network summary, confidential information has been omitted.

```
bridge200: connected to bridge200
        "bridge200"
        bridge, 02:68:9F:C2:CC:89, sw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.200.65/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.200.0/24
        inet6 fdfb:9584:eb33:2:68:9fff:fec2:cc89/64
        inet6 fe80::68:9fff:fec2:cc89/64
        route6 fdfb:9584:eb33:2::/64
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 ff00::/8

bridge3: connected to bridge3
        "bridge3"
        bridge, 5E:63:93:76:B0:89, sw, mtu 1500
        ip6 default
        inet4 192.168.3.98/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.3.0/24
        inet6 2001:4dd0:5033:3:2c25:758:1d92:5bd3/64
        inet6 2002:5c32:5c86:3:559:ec8c:9497:978e/64
        inet6 fdfb:9584:eb33:3:fb6a:32ab:5c91:d30a/64
        inet6 fe80::a85f:26b1:11d6:903c/64
        route6 2002:5c32:5c86:3::/64
        route6 fdfb:9584:eb33:3::/64
        route6 2001:4dd0:5033:3::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 2001:4dd0:5033:3::fed/128
        route6 2002:b0c7:bc86:83::fed/128
        route6 fdfb:9584:eb33:3::fed/128
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ff00::/8

bridge110: connected to bridge110
        "bridge110"
        bridge, B6:79:0D:6A:21:E0, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 172.20.32.15/24
        route4 172.20.32.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0

virbr0: connected (externally) to virbr0
        "virbr0"
        bridge, 52:54:00:72:A1:8F, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.122.1/24
        route4 192.168.122.0/24

enp43s0: connected to Wired connection 3
        "Mellanox MT26448"
        ethernet (mlx4_core), 00:02:C9:56:D6:DC, hw, port 0002c9030056d6dc, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.2.1/31
        route4 192.168.2.0/31

enp35s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel I210"
        ethernet (igb), D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, hw, mtu 1500
        master bridge3

vnet0: connected (externally) to vnet0
        "vnet0"
        tun, FE:54:00:23:76:BE, sw, mtu 1500
        master virbr0

enp35s0.110: connected to enp35s0.110
        "enp35s0.110"
        vlan, D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, sw, mtu 1500
        master bridge110

enp35s0.200: connected to enp35s0.200
        "enp35s0.200"
        vlan, D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, sw, mtu 1500
        master bridge200

enp36s0: unavailable
        "Intel I210"
        ethernet (igb), D0:50:99:D6:ED:54, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

macvtap0: unmanaged
        "macvtap0"
        macvlan (macvtap), 52:54:00:F1:D0:30, sw, mtu 1500

macvtap1: unmanaged
        "macvtap1"
        macvlan (macvtap), 52:54:00:C5:8B:10, sw, mtu 1500

macvtap10: unmanaged
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ff00::/8

bridge110: connected to bridge110
        "bridge110"
        bridge, B6:79:0D:6A:21:E0, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 172.20.32.15/24
        route4 172.20.32.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0

virbr0: connected (externally) to virbr0
        "virbr0"
        bridge, 52:54:00:72:A1:8F, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.122.1/24
        route4 192.168.122.0/24

enp43s0: connected to Wired connection 3
        "Mellanox MT26448"
        ethernet (mlx4_core), 00:02:C9:56:D6:DC, hw, port 0002c9030056d6dc, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.2.1/31
        route4 192.168.2.0/31

enp35s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel I210"
        ethernet (igb), D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, hw, mtu 1500
        master bridge3

vnet0: connected (externally) to vnet0
        "vnet0"
        tun, FE:54:00:23:76:BE, sw, mtu 1500
        master virbr0

enp35s0.110: connected to enp35s0.110
        "enp35s0.110"
        vlan, D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, sw, mtu 1500
        master bridge110

enp35s0.200: connected to enp35s0.200
        "enp35s0.200"
        vlan, D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, sw, mtu 1500
        master bridge200

enp36s0: unavailable
        "Intel I210"
        ethernet (igb), D0:50:99:D6:ED:54, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

macvtap0: unmanaged
        "macvtap0"
        macvlan (macvtap), 52:54:00:F1:D0:30, sw, mtu 1500

macvtap1: unmanaged
        "macvtap1"
        macvlan (macvtap), 52:54:00:C5:8B:10, sw, mtu 1500

macvtap10: unmanaged
bridge200: connected to bridge200
        "bridge200"
        bridge, 02:68:9F:C2:CC:89, sw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.200.65/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.200.0/24
        inet6 fdfb:9584:eb33:2:68:9fff:fec2:cc89/64
        inet6 fe80::68:9fff:fec2:cc89/64
        route6 fdfb:9584:eb33:2::/64
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 ff00::/8

bridge3: connected to bridge3
        "bridge3"
        bridge, 5E:63:93:76:B0:89, sw, mtu 1500
        ip6 default
        inet4 192.168.3.98/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.3.0/24
        inet6 2001:4dd0:5033:3:2c25:758:1d92:5bd3/64
        inet6 2002:5c32:5c86:3:559:ec8c:9497:978e/64
        inet6 fdfb:9584:eb33:3:fb6a:32ab:5c91:d30a/64
        inet6 fe80::a85f:26b1:11d6:903c/64
        route6 2002:5c32:5c86:3::/64
        route6 fdfb:9584:eb33:3::/64
        route6 2001:4dd0:5033:3::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 2001:4dd0:5033:3::fed/128
        route6 2002:b0c7:bc86:83::fed/128
        route6 fdfb:9584:eb33:3::fed/128
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ff00::/8

bridge110: connected to bridge110
        "bridge110"
        bridge, B6:79:0D:6A:21:E0, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 172.20.32.15/24
        route4 172.20.32.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0

virbr0: connected (externally) to virbr0
        "virbr0"
        bridge, 52:54:00:72:A1:8F, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.122.1/24
        route4 192.168.122.0/24

enp43s0: connected to Wired connection 3
        "Mellanox MT26448"
        ethernet (mlx4_core), 00:02:C9:56:D6:DC, hw, port 0002c9030056d6dc, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.2.1/31
        route4 192.168.2.0/31

enp35s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel I210"
        ethernet (igb), D0:50:99:D6:ED:53, hw, mtu 1500
        master bridge3
```

From `virsh dumpxml`

```
 <interface type='direct'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:04:c4:e3'/>
      <source dev='bridge200' mode='vepa'/>
      <target dev='macvtap5'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>

nmcli device status

DEVICE       TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION         
bridge200    bridge    connected               bridge200          
bridge3      bridge    connected               bridge3            
bridge110    bridge    connected               bridge110          
virbr0       bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0             
enp43s0      ethernet  connected               Wired connection 3 
enp35s0      ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1 
vnet0        tun       connected (externally)  vnet0              
enp35s0.110  vlan      connected               enp35s0.110        
enp35s0.200  vlan      connected               enp35s0.200        
enp36s0      ethernet  unavailable             --                 
lo           loopback  unmanaged               --                 
macvtap0     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap1     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap10    macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap11    macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap2     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap3     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap4     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap5     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap6     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap7     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap8     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
macvtap9     macvlan   unmanaged               --                 
virbr0-nic   tun       unmanaged               --
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue, checking a few different sources.
First step, according to https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html i had to add the following rules to

```
/etc/sysctl.conf


net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

According to the solution, quoted here, [Passthrough of VM's to local network (bridging) Fedora 31 Server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564353/passthrough-of-vms-to-local-network-bridging-fedora-31-server) i had to select "lan bridge" in order to attach the bridge200 interface instead of "direct attachment". That's what saved me and solved my issue!! Thanks a lot even though!

Comment: I can't find these in `/proc`. Any idea where they are now?